# android - pubnub - cant see messages and history

Tags: android, sockets, chat, message, pubnub

I use [Pubnub](https://www.pubnub.com/) to implement 1-1 chat between android devices.

I did the publish/subscribe tutorial and I am able to listen to a channel and send messages to a channel. When I send a message to the channel, the receive callback is called successfully.

My issue is - On the Pubnub admin dashboard, It says I have **1 Device** (true, because I subscribed and listened only from one device so far), but it also says there are **0 messages**, which is weird because I did send and received messages in the channel.

Where can I see the messages, channels and chat history? it also brings the question of how would I get the chat history for each channel..

Anyone with experience with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## PubNub Admin Dashboard - Metrics

The metrics in the [PubNub Admin Dashboard](https://admin.pubnub.com) are calculated daily so what you see there is *as of* yesterday.

- [Daily Active Devices](https://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/discussion/301/how-are-active-devices-counted) is the day with the highest number of devices that connected to PubNub using your keys.
- [Message count](https://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/discussion/497/how-are-messages-counted) is the cumulative message from the beginning of the current month.

Check again tomorrow and you should see the message counts metrics with non-zero numbers.

Comment: got it, thanks. I can see now that numbers updated. thanks a lot!